# creating dynamic rows in JSP/Servlets instead of javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Is there any alternative mechanism creating dynamic rows in JSP/Servlets instead of javascript.

JS Code:-

```
var table = document.getElementById('table1');  
                  var tr    = document.createElement('TR');
    var td1   = document.createElement('TD');
    var td2   = document.createElement('TD');
    var td3   = document.createElement('TD');
    var td4   = document.createElement('TD');
    var inp1  = document.createElement('INPUT');
    var inp2  = document.createElement('INPUT');
                 var inp3  = document.createElement('INPUT');
    inp1.setAttribute("Name", "purpose");
    inp1.setAttribute("id", purpose"+reclength); 
    inp2.setAttribute("Name", "Amount");
    inp2.setAttribute("id", "Amount"+reclength);  
    inp3.setAttribute("Name", "dt");
    inp3.setAttribute("id", "dt"+reclength);  
    var deleteIcon     = document.createElement('IMG');
    deleteIcon.setAttribute('src', '<%=basePath%>images/cancelIcon.gif');
    deleteIcon.onclick = function(){
        removeWthDrwls(tr);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);
    td1.appendChild(inp1);
    td2.appendChild(inp2);
    td3.appendChild(inp3);
    td3.appendChild(space2);
    td3.appendChild(deleteIcon);
```

but if user has disabled javascript.So what are best ways to provide alternative solution to him/her in java web applications?

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you can do the same in jsp refer [JSP: Creating Dynamic Tables](http://www.developer.com/lang/other/article.php/724201/JSP-Creating-Dynamic-Tables.htm)

here example is given how you can create a table in the jsp same way you can create dynamic rows..

Ten columns can be added for each row by nesting another for loop within the TR tag as follows:

```
<TABLE>
<% for(int row=1; row <= 5; row++) { %>
    <TR>
<%      for(int col=1; col<=10; col++) { %>
        <TD> (<%=col%>, <%=row%>)
        </TD>
        <% } %>
    </TR>
<% } %>
</TABLE>
```

Each cell contains its row and column numbers as the tuple (col, row).

Comment: But How to increment row dyanamcially based on button event.

Comment: you can store data in back and on page refresh you can display the list in form of a table.